# Output repeating itself when displaying output [Java]

Tags: java

I'm working on a program for a class at school, that requires us to write a Java program to get a String from a user, then print out the number of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and whitespaces. The code works fine, the problem with it, is that it repeats the same output twice.

**Code:**

```
    String isUp = "";
    String isLo = "";
    int spaceCount;
    System.out.print("Please give a string: ");
    String x = input.nextLine();
    int z = x.length();
    for(int y = 0; y < z; y++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(x.charAt(y))){
            char u = x.charAt(y);
            isUp = isUp + u + " ";
        }
        if (Character.isLowerCase(x.charAt(y))){
            char v = x.charAt(y);
            isLo = isLo + v + " ";
        }
        spaceCount = 0;
        for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                spaceCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The uppercase characters are " + isUp);
        System.out.println("The lowercase characters are " + isLo);
        System.out.println("The number of whitespaces is " + spaceCount);
    }
```

The output I'm getting is: (String used: "Stack Overflow")

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laiWn.jpg)

How can I make it so I'm only getting one output? Help would be appreciated, and if there was something on the Java API that I missed, feel free to tell me! (Without downvotes) Thanks!

Comment: Your `System.out.println` statements are inside the `for-loop` so they will be repeated `z - 1` times

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried moving them outside of the `for` loop, and it gives me: `Error:(69, 62) java: variable spaceCount might not have been initialized`.

Comment: @Yoshi24517 initialize you `spaceCount` variable to `0` when you declare it

Comment: Change `int spaceCount;`  to `int spaceCount = 0;`. As a general hint, it's very rare that a local variable shouldn't be assigned an initial value, it just makes life easier ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The `spacecount = 0` statement inside the `for` loop; with your edit to making it `int spaceCount = 0;`, do I need to keep it to 0?

Comment: @Yoshi24517 the statement inside the `for` loop is correct. What @MadProgrammer is referring to is to initialize your variable to 0 when you declare it

Comment: Testing, give me a minute.

Comment: @Yoshi24517 I'd remove the one in the loop, as you kind of need that value after the loop has finished. As far as the compiler is concerned, it's possible for the code in the loop to never be executed (a `String` if `0` length for example), meaning that `spacecount` is undefined

Comment: @Yoshi24517 the `for` loop which calculates the `spaceCount` can be taken out of the outer `for` loop and placed outside as `spaceCount` only needs to be calculated once, not `z - 1` times

Comment: @MadProgrammer It worked fine! Now just write an answer for it, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `println` statements are inside you `for` loop. Move them outside of the `for` loop.

Also, you will have to initialize your `spaceCount` variable when you declare it.

Comment: What about the changing of the `int spaceCount`?

Comment: Yes you would have to initialize your `spaceCount` variable when you declare it.

Comment: Also note to get the correct `spacecount` you will have to remove the inner for loop and have it by itself. Otherwise the total `spacecount` value will be incorrect. Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to B.Naeem's answer, you loop could be simplifed to something like..

```
for(int y = 0; y < z; y++){
    if (Character.isUpperCase(x.charAt(y))){
        char u = x.charAt(y);
        isUp = isUp + u + " ";
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(x.charAt(y))){
        char v = x.charAt(y);
        isLo = isLo + v + " ";
    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(x.charAt(y))) {
        spaceCount++;
    }
}
```

Basically or this does is checks to see if the character is upper cased or lower cased or a space, as if it's any one of these, it can't be the other

Answer (score 0):

Move your print statements outside your `for` loop. Also, remove `spaceCount = 0;` from your loop. Instead, replace `int spaceCount;` with `int spaceCount = 0;`.